Two answers to one problem, but both seem correct (mathematically)
The question is:

Two particles are performing SHM along the $x$-axis and about the origin. If the maximum separation between them is equal to their amplitude $A$, find the phase difference.

Method 1- Using the phasor diagram and equating the $y$ coordinates of the particle, we can obtain the phase difference to be $\pi/3$.
Method 2- Let the first particle has equation given as $x= A \sin(\omega t+P)$, and second particle has $x=A \sin(\omega t+Q)$.
The separation is: $$A \sin(\omega t+P)-A \sin(\omega t+Q).$$
Applying $\sin(C) - \sin(D)$, separation is $$2A \sin \left[2 \omega t+\frac{P+Q}{2}\right] \cos\left(\frac{P-Q}{2}\right).$$
For maximum separation to be $A$, the term with $\cos$ should be equal to $1/2$ ($\sin$ term can be $1$ at a particular time), so $(P-Q)=2\pi/3$.
Both seem mathematically correct, but when we analyse, the second method is wrong. Why?

better suited for math stack exchange?

You have simply remembered the identities wrongly.
$$\begin{align}
\tag1   &A\left[\sin(\omega t+P)-\sin(\omega t+Q)\right]\\
\tag2\label{eq:2}=\,&A\left[
          \sin\left\{\left(\omega t+\frac{P+Q}2\right)+\frac{P-Q}2\right\}
         -\sin\left\{\left(\omega t+\frac{P+Q}2\right)-\frac{P-Q}2\right\}\right]\\
\tag3\label{eq:3}=2&A\cos \left(\omega t+\frac{P+Q}2\right)\sin\frac{P-Q}2\\
\tag4&\therefore\qquad\sin\frac{P-Q}2=\frac12\quad\implies\quad P-Q=\frac\pi3,\end{align}$$
where the step from Equation $\eqref{eq:2}$ to Equation $\eqref{eq:3}$ used the identity that
$$\tag5\sin(A+B)-\sin(A-B)=\sin A\cos B+\cos A\sin B-(\sin A\cos B-\cos A\sin B).$$
